# Open layer 3 label

Tags: openlayers-3

I have seen this link: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/examples/vector-labels.html

But how can I have a label with a background rectangle of a chosen color, to improve the readability (such as white text over a black rectangle) ?

Comment: Background rectangle in a text label is not currently supported in ol3.  However, you could use a high "outline width" value.  Try putting "6" as "O. Width" it in the above example to see what I mean.  It improves readability too.

Comment: @AlexandreDubé I have tried this, but the output is not what I'm looking for. Would it not be possible, though, to just draw a rectangle below the text ?

Comment: To my knowledge, this feature is not supported in ol3 but not impossible.  You could work on a Pull Request to have it added to the library.